# Monotouch UIPopover iPhone override _popoversDisabled

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I saw this video on youtube where, in objective-c he was able to override the _popoversDisabled method and allow them to be displayed on iPhones.

My Question is, how would I do the same thing in monotouch as shown as below:

```
This code was written by @hamzasood
===============================
=====popover code===========
=============================
@interface UIPopoverController (overrides)
+ (BOOL)_popoversDisabled;
@end

@implementation UIPopoverController (overrides)

+ (BOOL)_popoversDisabled { return NO;
}

@end
```

Objective-C video tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iykxemuxbk&feature=related

Comment: I'm pretty sure that overriding that method (which is almost definitely private) will get your app rejected from the App Store.

Comment: I understand that. Just trying to learn.

Comment: It will get rejected, yes. It's a private var.

Comment: Sometimes Apple does not reject apps for this. I am the guy who made the youtube and have a app in the app store that was approved with this code in the app. Its been years since Ive updated the app so I don't know if Apple has cracked down on this, or if it just depends on the reviewer but it worked in iOS 5 and submitted multiple updates back then with 0 issues